# How to get the OAuth token to be assigned to my HttpClient using .Net Core 2.2 AddHttpClient?

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-authorization, auth-token, httpclientfactory

I'm writing an Asp.Net Core 2.2 application in which I'm adding HttpClient.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(o => {
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddQuickbooksOnline(o => {
                o.ClientId = Configuration["ecm.qbo.client-id"];
                o.ClientSecret = Configuration["ecm.qbo.client-secret"];
                o.Scope.Add(QuickbooksOnlineScopes.Accounting);
            });

        services.AddHttpClient("qbo", c => {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization=// How do I get the token to be assigned here?
        });

        service.AddScoped<IInventoryService, QboInventoryService>();
```

So, basically I wrote myself an extension which allows me to AddQuickbooksOnline authentication using minimal configuration as many configurations is made by default by the extension.

Once registered and authenticated to my app, I display a GetProducts button to the authenticated user.

I want this button to call upon my ProductController.

```
public class ProductController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly IInventoryService _inventoryService;
    public ProductController(IInventoryService inventoryService) {
        _inventoryService=inventoryService??throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inventoryService));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Get() {
        var products=await _inventoryService.GetAllProducts();
        return products;
    }
}
```

And the service actually depends on the configured HttpClient I want to add in my services configuration.

```
public class QboInventoryService : IInventoryService {
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public QboInventoryService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration config) {
        _clientFactory=clientFactory??throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientFactory));
        _config=config??throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProducts() {
        IEnumerable<Product> products=new List<Product>();

        var client=_clientFactory.CreateClient("qbo");
        var response=await client.GetAsync(config["qbo.products.query"]);

        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var content=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            products=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Product>>(content);
        }

        return products;
    }
}
```

So, in order to make my call to the QBO WebAPI, I need to provide the OAuth token of authenticated user to the HttpClient being instantiated.

Comment: The null check isnt needed in your constructors - the DI framework will automatically throw an exception if the injection cannot be satisfied ;-)

Comment: Also, what actually is your question? Its not clear

Comment: @RobertPerry, thx for your attention. If you look at the first code sample, the line where `services.AddHttpClient` is called, look at the initialization. `c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization=???` You see my question there when looked for carefully.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, you're absolutely right! It's exactly that I wanted. Thx for pointing me to an answer. :)